# Uploading same video on same channel but shorter

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-channel

Running a YouTube jokes series, each video 15 minutes long.
In each video, there are 10 categories (10 different "types" of jokes). Each category aims at different types of watchers, and each category has a name (lower third) so people can connect with it better.

From comments, it's obvious that some people like one type of jokes (categories) and others like different ones. Usually, they write "that category is awesome, can't wait for more".

Videos we publish must stay in full length (15 mins) because of sponsorship, but for those people that come back and want to see all jokes in a specific category from all past videos, we would like to create playlists.

So, leaving the main videos as they are in full length, we are thinking about creating 10 playlists which would carry category names and uploading 1-2min. videos that are cut from the main video.

Would YouTube consider this spam?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, there isn't any mention or restriction that would forbid you to upload partially same context again. this can't be (by any means) considered as spamming Youtube.

> **Spam, misleading metadata and scams**
>
> Don't create misleading descriptions, tags, titles or thumbnails in order to increase views.
> It's not okay to post large amounts of untargeted, unwanted or
> repetitive content, including comments and private messages.
>
> **https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2801973?hl=en-GB**

That something what you want to do is just not common practice mostly because it requires a lot of uploading applied again and in some cases, it can lead to the shortage of views per video if you aim to promote those longer videos. in other cases, it can be a good move to gain more views hence more popularity - so at the end of a day its a good marketing move that will cost you painfull uploading of those shorts.

Comment: Thinking how Google ranks duplicate content on webpages, this could be considered similar thing. Policies on webpages as on Youtube do not mention that you can not do it, but my guess is it could potentially hurt your Youtube channel SEO ? Uploading shorts is not a problem if it will lead to good results.

Comment: @Azz Kawa if those shorts are not stolen from a different channel and claimed as original production of your channel, then all is good because only otherwise this could be considered as spamming with duplicate content, however even then youtube wouldn't mind the spam issue, because its irrelevant in comparison to copyright violation